# Does the echo command append any extra character when writing to text file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a shortcut using batch file. I mimic the following manual steps to do that, but although the manually created file works properly as a shortcut, the shortcut created by batch files command line command does not work-

Creating shortcuts manually:

1. Create a text file
2. Add following content to the text file and save:

   ```
   [InternetShortcut]
   URL=file:///D:\Logs
   ```
3. Rename the text file to have .url extension.

That process creates a shortcut to D:\Logs directory.

Now I do the following to create shortcut using Batch file-

```
(
ECHO [InternetShortcut]
ECHO URL=file:///D:\Logs
) > E:\myshortcut.url
```

But the shortcut does not work. I checked the contents and they look exactly as what I have in the manually created file.

So what is the difference between those manually created and batch file created files?

Comment: `echo` will add a CR+LF sequence at the end of each line.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/455364/how-to-create-a-shortcut-using-a-batch-script?

Comment: @Phylogenesis How can I escape those when writing to file?

Comment: Copying your batch-file as shown above works for me (Windows 7)... is this _exactly_ the batch file you're using, or have you got `%variables%` etc.? If so, edit-in the exact script you're using.

Comment: @TripeHound I first tried to use variables to take the locations as params, but then I tried with hardcoded locations, exactly as the above snippet (and also removing the space before angle brace as suggested by one, and echoing seperately, and also writing the first echo and appending the second), none is working unfortunately. A file created from cmd does not work at all, even if I create it as .txt and then check the contents and rename it as .url. I am on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
echo [InternetShortcut]> E:\myshortcut.url
echo URL=file:///D:\Logs>> E:\myshortcut.url
```

Note that you must **not** have a space before the redirection `>` or `>>` because that *will* be echoed into the file.